# How do you parsing nested JSON data for specific information?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm using the national weather service API and when you use a specific URL you get JSON data back. My program so far grabs everything including 155 hours of weather data.

- Simply put I'm trying to parse the data and grab the weather for the
  latest hour but everything is in a nested data structure.

My code, JSON data, and more information are below. Any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
import json

def get_current_weather():  #This method returns json data from the api
    url = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/*office*/*any number,*any number*/forecast/hourly'
    response = requests.get(url)
    full_data = response.json()
    return full_data  

def main():   #Prints the information grabbed from the API
    print(get_current_weather())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the JSON response, I get there are 3 layers before you get to the 'shortForecast' data that I'm trying to get. The first nest is 'properties, everything before it is irrelevant to my program. The second nest is 'periods' and each period is a new hour, 0 being the latest. Lastly, I just need to grab the 'shortForcast' in the first period or periods[0].

```
{
    "@context": [
        "https://geojson.org/geojson-ld/geojson-context.jsonld",
        {
            "@version": "1.1",
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "geo": "http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#",
            "unit": "http://codes.wmo.int/common/unit/",
            "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"
        }
    ],
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                *data I'm not gonna add*
            ]
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "updated": "2021-02-11T05:57:24+00:00",
        "units": "us",
        "forecastGenerator": "HourlyForecastGenerator",
        "generatedAt": "2021-02-11T07:12:58+00:00",
        "updateTime": "2021-02-11T05:57:24+00:00",
        "validTimes": "2021-02-10T23:00:00+00:00/P7DT14H",
        "elevation": {
            "value": ,
            "unitCode": "unit:m"
        },
        "periods": [
            {
                "number": 1,
                "name": "",
                "startTime": "2021-02-11T02:00:00-05:00",
                "endTime": "2021-02-11T03:00:00-05:00",
                "isDaytime": false,
                "temperature": 18,
                "temperatureUnit": "F",
                "temperatureTrend": null,
                "windSpeed": "10 mph",
                "windDirection": "N",
                "icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/snow,40?size=small",
                "shortForecast": "Chance Light Snow",
                "detailedForecast": ""
            },
            {
                "number": 2,
                "name": "",
                "startTime": "2021-02-11T03:00:00-05:00",
                "endTime": "2021-02-11T04:00:00-05:00",
                "isDaytime": false,
                "temperature": 17,
                "temperatureUnit": "F",
                "temperatureTrend": null,
                "windSpeed": "12 mph",
                "windDirection": "N",
                "icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/snow,40?size=small",
                "shortForecast": "Chance Light Snow",
                "detailedForecast": ""
            },
```

OK, so I didn't want to edit everything again so this is the new get_current_weather method. I was able to get to 'periods but after that I'm still stumped. This is the new method.

```
def get_current_weather():  
    url = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/ILN/82,83/forecast/hourly'
    response = requests.get(url)
    full_data = response.json()
    return full_data['properties'].get('periods')
```

Comment: by using key. Example `fulldata['properties']['updated']`

Comment: `full_data['properties']['periods'][0]['shortForecast]` will give you the value for `shortForecast` key in the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dictionary object, you can access the nested elements by using indexing multiple times.

So, for your dictionary object, you can use the following to get the value for the key `shortForecast` for the first element in the list of dictionaries under key `periods` under the key `properties` in the main dictionary:

```
full_data['properties']['periods'][0]['shortForecast']
```